# Convert Invoice Page Excel to PDF Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, pdf-generation

I have invoices on two different sheets in a workbook, one for distributors Invoice and one for online sales, I have to convert them to PDF when need and save them in a folder. I have a code but it works on one sheet.

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
Dim filename As String
filename = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\INVOICE OUT RESTORE\INVOICE SERIAL WISE\" & Range("L8").Value
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties _
:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Both sheets have their own buttons for running macros.

I need such a code that whenever I need I can use the macro button of the corresponding sheet and get the PDF.

Comment: Your code is correct but should be run by the right way, look at my answer. You can also look at the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct if it's run from the button on the worksheet, it should print out this sheet. This is *guaranteed by using the ActiveSheet* object.

Just check it once again:

1. The macro should reside in a module not in sheet's codepage.
2. Every sheet has a button to directly run this macro.

Check pdfs against sheets. If the macro isn't run directly, *check if ActiveSheet is not changed by the early code*.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you both so much. Glad to see the academic discussion in a positive manner۔

Comment: Please perform checks as stated above.

Comment: Please accept and/or rate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SaveAsPDF1()
Dim filename As String
filename = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\INVOICE OUT RESTORE\INVOICE SERIAL WISE\" & Worksheets("distributors_Invoice").Range("L8").Value
Worksheets("distributors_Invoice").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties _
:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub

Sub SaveAsPDF2()
Dim filename As String
filename = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\INVOICE OUT RESTORE\INVOICE SERIAL WISE\" & Worksheets("online_sales").Range("L8").Value
Worksheets("online_sales").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties _
:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Replace the Worksheets name with the appropriate sheet name.

Presumed that the file names are on the two sheets in the same cell "L8"

Assign for the two command buttons the two Sub name.

Comment: It's a solution, but extra. The original code is correct and should work.

Comment: In this case it would be good to put each macro into worksheet's code page not into a common module and replace 'Worksheets("sheetName")' just with 'Me'.

Comment: @rotabor The OP code works only correctly if the activesheet is the one which want to be saved and not placed in a Sheet codepane. Defining range without an object qualifier is dangerous, only if you exactly know what does the code and the user do. The answer is not extra but required for a more exact approach of the task. (The command buttons can be placed on any sheet or on the ribbon.

Comment: If OP code run by a button on the sheet (as OP wrote, it seems like) the ActiveSheet is the sheet where the button is clicked. And Range is applied to ActiveSheet. If a button on the ribbon, the code will work with ActiveSheet as well as previously. The only concern is if sub is called from another one and ActiveSheet is intentionally changed.

Comment: If this macro is on the sheet's codepage, it's possible to assign it to the button on another sheet, but it will produce an error when clicked outside (at least with MS Forms button, I tested).

Comment: @rotabor `Both sheets have their own buttons for running macros.` doesn't mean in **English** that they are on the corresponding sheet.

Comment: Sure. We don't know exactly how it works. By the way I explained all cases.

Comment: Thank you both so much. Glad to see the academic discussion in a positive manner۔ Actually it was specific to one sheet first I assigned a macro to a button and did the same in another sheet as per my requirement but when I tried both at the same time it failed once it worked only on one sheet Whether it is the first or the second۔

Comment: I can't check it right now because of a problem with my laptop. I will check on Monday and let you know.

Comment: @Black cat -  The problem is the same, the code is valid on the first sheet but giving an error on the second sheet.

Comment: @rotabor. Sir matter still not solved. I follow your instructions. even then

Comment: @kalim This means that the code is correct. There is some error in the parameters: 1. The commandbutton assignment sub name (Right click the command button and in the popup window select (`Assign Macro`), and click `SaveAsPDF2`. 2. The worksheet name is mistyped. 3. The "L8" cell value not correspond to a correct filename.